# Debugging "upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream"

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, debugging

I am running an nginx + php-fpm setup. I recently ran into problem returning binary data to the Nginx server. Nginx show this in the error log:

```
2021/08/04 19:22:27 [error] 996463#996463: *1 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI request while reading upstream, client: 192.168.1.10, server: foobar.com, request: "GET /somemedia.mp4 HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "foobar.com", referrer: "https://foobar.com/somemedia.mp4"
```

But I got no error in php-fpm or in my php script. Any suggestion how I should start tackling this issue? Please help.

Comment: Don't send requests for static content to PHP.

Comment: There's a reason I proxy the static content request with PHP. And I don't see why there should be any issue here.